# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion, seven-questions

Straight from [the 7 essential meta questions of every beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:
>
> - the tagline
> - the motto
> - the blurb under the logo
> - a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
> - perhaps eventually the domain name [in some form](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)
>
> (Due to a variety of [practical difficulties with domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their topic.stackexchange.com names indefinitely.)
>
> Naming is hard — really hard. But if you can come up with a sensible elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.
>
> For more detail see: [Stack Exchange Naming for Dummies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/)

Answer (score 6):

I think we should come up with a pitch that steers us from the “man versus the wild” viewpoint, which I find too aggresive and proud for my taste. As an example of the opposite approach, I like the title of the book [Mountaineering: The Freedom of the Hills](http://books.google.com/books?id=QupdBAEgpGEC). Feeling the freedom and being more aware of myself are the primary reasons that make me go outside. I’d like the motto to be *Enjoying the nature’s embrace, however hard* or something along that line (not a native English speaker, sorry).

Comment: I like the idea of something along those lines - "Enjoying nature's freedom"?

Comment: I like a motto that emphasizes *freedom*. But I'm not a fan of "nature's embrace;" nature doesn't actually embrace people. It's deadly and unforgiving, and it feels less than genuine to say otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Just to bump a suggestion to this one again, since it's probably something that needs a bit more thought!

- The Great Outdoors: Leave no trace
- The Great Outdoors: Track ahead
- The Great Outdoors: Don't trail behind, track ahead
- The Great Outdoors: Natural survival
- The Great Outdoors: Harmonising with nature's embrace

As for the tagline:

- Tracking ahead with solid advice
- How to enjoy nature's freedom, safely and responsibly

In truth I'm not fully convinced by any of those, but firmly believe the best ideas often come after bouncing around a number of others!

Answer (score 1):

- **Tagline:** You're never alone in The Great Outdoors.
- **Alternate name (for URL):** either "funinthesun" or "leaveonlyfootprints"

Things I am less sure about (and are expendable, but I'm leaving these here instead of editing them out so folks can see what the first two comments were about):

- **Motto:** Mmmm... these are sounding hokey, but something along the lines of:  Learning about the outdoors together.  No question is a stupid question.  Chances are, if you've been wondering something about the great outdoors, somebody here will have an answer for you-- let's find out together.
- **Blurb under the logo:** Instead of learning about the great outdoors from a faceless expert, let's all become outdoors experts together.

Comment: I like the tagline, Not sure about the rest though.

Comment: I like the tagline and the "leaveonlyfootprints" URL - I'm not so keen on the whole "let's do it together" line, to it makes it seem a bit more like a self help group rather than a Q&A site!

Comment: These are ideas, feel free to take or leave whatever part of them you'd like. ;)

Comment: @ClareSteen I wouldn't worry - you've come up with more than I have! Picking something is always best even if it doesn't hold...

Answer (score -5):

Our motto should cover the idea that *outdoorsmanship*, in whatever form, is pitting person against nature. Our answers --the good ones -- give outdoorsmen (that's *men* as in olde english for person, not as a sexist slight against women) the edge against the elements.

Comment: I agree with others - "pitting person (man, woman, or old english men) against nature" is way off. I have never once felt in an adversarial relationship with the back-country.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not a fan of pretending that nature *embraces* people, but I suppose the community has spoken.